# Data layout issue from MySQL in PDF using TCPDF write1DBarcode

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

I'm trying to extract MySQL numeric data with TCPDF in order to create a PDF file with a list of 1D barcodes. The database records are dynamically changing and growing. Each line is autoincremented by 1.

The problem is that I need to a have a list of 8 to 10 barcodes per page organized in two columns but I can't manage to call data in even/odd order. Each line displays only the first two records.

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
  |     1     |    2    |
_________________________
1 |  1st code | 2nd code

2 |  3rd code | 4th code
```

... and so on...

What I get instead:

```
  |     1     |    2    |
_________________________
1 |  1st code | 2nd code

2 |  1st code | 2nd code
```

Here is my PHP - TCPDF code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

$id = $row['id'];
$barcode = $row['barcode'];

if ($id % 2 != 0 & $id <= 2)
{

for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i=$i+2)
{
$x = 15;
  $y = 25;
        $pdf->write1DBarcode($barcode, 'C39', $x, $y, '120', 18, 0.4,   $style, 'N');
}

for ($i = 1; $i < 2; $i=$i+2)
{
$x = 110;
$y = 25;
        $pdf->write1DBarcode($barcode, 'C39', $x, $y, '120', 18, 0.4,   $style, 'N');
    }
}
elseif ($id % 2 == 0 & $id <= 2)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i=$i+2)
{
$x = 15;
  $y = 50;
        $pdf->write1DBarcode($barcode, 'C39', $x, $y, '120', 18, 0.4,   $style, 'N');
}

for ($i = 1; $i < 2; $i=$i+2)
{
$x = 110;
$y = 50;
        $pdf->write1DBarcode($barcode, 'C39', $x, $y, '120', 18, 0.4,   $style, 'N');
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: none of your 'for' loops will execute more than once - is this correct functionality? Other than that I can't entirely figure out what you're trying to achieve. Can you clarify further?